# Responsive variants for custom configured classes

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I've added more padding sizes to my tailwind.config.js. I can access the new padding sizes from my React components, and I can use them in my CSS files. However I can't use the responsive variants in my CSS files like `md:p-140` etc.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      padding: {
        '140': '35rem'
      }
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

I am able to use `@apply pb-140` inside my CSS files, but if I use `@apply md:pb-140`, the class does not exist. The variants work when I use it in a React component, just not in CSS files. The variants for the default classes work with `@apply` though, like `@apply md:p-8`.

How can I get variants to work with classes added by my tailwind config?

Comment: Works fine in Tailwind Play [see here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/6hra1sLyW9) maybe it's a config issue.

Comment: It should work. You are doing something else wrong that we cannot see in this question.